# Add Link Button in specific location

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, append, linkbutton

My current scenario is I retrieved the *HTML* of a page using the following method.

```
 readStream = New StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet))
 Dim fullString As String = readStream.ReadToEnd()
```

I did further formatting of the *HTML* before setting it to the *innerHtml* of my *div*.

```
 displaystring = Regex.Replace(fullString, "<div.*?>", "<div>")
 displaystring = Regex.Replace(fullString, "<span.*?>", "<span>")
 displaystring = Regex.Replace(fullString, "<table.*?>", "<table>")
```

For example, I have a part of *HTML* code which is

```
<a>Brazil</a>
```

And I have tried `fullstring = Regex.Replace(fullstring, "<a>Brzail</a>", <asp:Linkbutton name="lnkTest" runat="server")`. And I realized it cannot work because *ASP controls* cannot be appended as *string*.

How can I `control.Add` just after `<a>Brazil</a>`? Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add ASP.Net Server control like this. You can use html control anchor tag or button and on click of  this you can make an AJAX call.
Sample code will be like this

```
fullstring = Regex.Replace(fullstring, "<a>Brzail</a>", "<a href='#' onclick='clickMe'>Link</a>")
```

In Server side C# you can write a page method
like `

```
[PageMethod]
public static string MyMethod()
{
//Your logic
  return "";
}
```

`
In javascript

```
function cickMe()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "Sample.aspx/MyMethod",
        success: function(data){
        //your logic
      }
    });
}
```